# How can I produce audio files for my choir to practice with from my Encore source?

Tags: software

I use Encore (from Passport Software) to create sheet music.  Members of my choir would like to be able to practice against audio files in various configurations (a mix with everything but their part, *just* their part for learning, etc).  I can use Encore's playback to make any of those configurations come out of my computer's speakers just fine.  Piping that signal to an MP3, on the other hand, is stumping me.

Encore can't directly create audio files.  I've tried using both Audacity and Amadeus Pro to record the playback from Encore, but both of those applications seem to want an "external" input, like a mic -- I don't see a way to pipe the audio from Encore into one of those applications.  I suppose I *could* hold the mic on my USB headset up to the cheap speakers on my computer and record that way, but that would be pretty lossy.  I don't need stellar sound (and don't have the equipment to produce it), but I'd like it to be clean.

Encore can export MIDI, but when I loaded that MIDI into the other two programs I got something that wouldn't play back.  I was able to use Amadeus Pro to export MP3 from the MIDI and got a 0-second track.  I don't have anything other than Encore that *reads* MIDI, so I don't know if the fault is with Encore's export or something else.

How should I be attacking this problem without buying more software?  (Free is fine.)  I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Jack osx. It's Free software, it lets you route audio+MIDI in practically any way possible. Only downside is that it can be a pain to get working on some setups. www.jackosx.com